# Image scraping with "Scrapy" getting no results

Tags: python, image, web-crawler, scrapy

I have been trying to use Scrapy to crawl Imgur for images but I'm running into problems.

The spider seems to work fine but it's failing to go on to the site and do the work.

I cant find the place I screw up..

items.py

```
import scrapy


class ImgurItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
```

setting.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'imgur'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['imgur.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'imgur.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = '\Users\123\Desktop\images'
```

imgur_spider.py

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from imgur.items import ImgurItem

class ImgurSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'imgur'
    allowed_domains = ['imgur.com']
    start_url = ['http://imgur.com']
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/gallery/.*']), 'parse_imgur')]

    def parse_imgur(self, response):
        image = ImgurItem()
        image['title'] = response.xpath("//h2[@id='image-title']/text()").extract()
        rel = response.xpath("//img/@src").extract()
        image['image_urls'] = ['http:'+rel[0]]
        return image
```

Log

```
2015-10-16 16:36:50 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: imgur)
2015-10-16 16:36:50 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-10-16 16:36:50 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'imgur.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['imgur.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'imgur'}
2015-10-16 16:36:50 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-10-16 16:36:50 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-10-16 16:36:50 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-10-16 16:36:50 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: ImagesPipeline
2015-10-16 16:36:50 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-10-16 16:36:50 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped     0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-16 16:36:50 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on   127.0.0.1:6023
2015-10-16 16:36:50 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-10-16 16:36:50 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 16, 15, 36, 50, 469000),
'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
'log_count/INFO': 7,
'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 16, 15, 36, 50, 462000)}
2015-10-16 16:36:50 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your crawler is going to https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rlnf7.jpg, then looking for all links containing "/gallery/" (the extra .* isn't needed).  It isn't finding any (because there are none on the page), and so the crawler finishes.

EDIT:
After cleaning up the code, it jumped out that `start_url = ...` should be `start_urls = ...`.  As is, Scrapy is grabbing nothing because it isn't being provided with anywhere to start.

Comment: Oh thats my bad! Forgot to change it back.. should be 'http://imgur.com/' being the front page where it should move in to the gallerys. The problem is still there tho.

Comment: @user2514200 I changed that, and corrected your indentation in the provided code.  Before I continue, can you check to make sure it accurately represents what you have in your crawler now?

Comment: Yes, except for the removal of the extra * you mentioned.

Comment: @user2514200 I've updated my answer, which should resolve the problem.

Comment: Brilliant. I wish I had your hawkeye! Thanks!